# Understanding some representations of categories

Tags: category-theory

I am very new to categories and trying to understand what does it mean. I understood that it consists of arrows and points linked between them and satisfying axioms of identity and composition. I tried to look for examples and found this one. The first thing I noticed is that the arrow going from a point A to the same point A (the identity) is missing, how can it be a category then ? (There also some missing compositions)

[image: Example 1]

Then I considered this second example found on the Internet too. Here, the identity arrows are all here, no problem. But there is an arrow from Unit to Int, and an arrow from Int to Real, but no composition arrow from Unit to Real ?! I think I am definitely the one missing something with this category concept.
[image: Example 2]

Comment: You are right that those things are missing. I suspect that when they make these drawings they expect you to fill in the missing arrows in your head to avoid cluttering the drawing. So, the actual category they are representing is obtained by taking every possible composition.

Comment: Also, not, $\mathrm{succ}_{\mathrm{int}}$ and $\mathrm{succ}_{\mathrm{Real}}$ don't sound like the identity to me. I think the second picture is also missing the identity arrows.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the loops around each node to itself is missing. Maybe that text assumes them to be always present, the second one also has no identities.

Just assume that the ientities are there.

The double ended arrow $\Leftrightarrow$ in the first picture stands for two arrows, I think: one in each direction.

The compositions are all there: for any two arrows there is only one arrow that could be the composition and the obvious candidate is that composition (minimality principle, as it were); this implies that the composition of the two arrows in $\Leftrightarrow$ is the (hidden) identity arrow so that those two points at the right side are isomorphic.

The composition of the arrow from Unit to Int sand "toReal" is just the map "zero" from Unit to Real. It's indeed sloppy that's not explicitly mentioned. The successor map from Int to Int is of course not the identity nor is the "not" map.

Comment: In the first drawing, we can consider the arrow going from the up right point (lets call it A) to the bottom point B; there is also an arrow going from B to the up left point C. There must exist an arrow from A to C (but there is just an C $\to$ A) so isn't it missing ?

Comment: @John I think indeed that some arrow $C \to A$ is missing there. Where's the example from?

Comment: From Wikipedia lol here is the link, it is the first picture you will see https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9orie_des_cat%C3%A9gories

Comment: @John the way to interpret a directed graph as a category is unclear. Maybe the book in the footnote explains this better?